# Ajax user notification when the status is success

Tags: jquery, ajax, push-notification

I'm working in django project where im performing a background task with celery which user can't see, from that I have a url some thing like this to check the status of the task,

```
'/tasks/3dbf226a-a7f5-4e9b-8094-4ad1383aa6fd/status/'
```

form this i get json response like

When the task is running:

```
{
    "task": {
        "status": "PENDING", 
        "result": null, 
        "id": "3dbf226a-a7f5-4e9b-8094-4ad1383aa6fd"
    }
}
```

When the task is completed:

```
{
    "task": {
        "status": "SUCCESS", 
        "result": null, 
        "id": "3dbf226a-a7f5-4e9b-8094-4ad1383aa6fd"
    }
}
```

I want to use AJAX and keep on checking the status, from the above json if the status changed to 'success' i need a notification or a some message in the page to notify the user that the task is completed successfully(like in facebook or twitter), if close and open the browser, the notification should remain there until the user clicks it., I'm very  new to ajax, can anyone please help me to achieve this. how to do this in ajax  call, .if my approach is wrong please guide me to proper way, if there any other way to achieve this please suggest me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout()` to poll the URL you have and wait for the `SUCCESS` status, something like this:

```
function checkTaskStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tasks/3dbf226a-a7f5-4e9b-8094-4ad1383aa6fd/status/',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json.task.status == 'SUCCESS') {
                // show a message to the user
            } else {
                setTimeout(checkTaskStatus, 10000); // try again in 10 seconds
            }
        }
    });
}

checkTaskStatus(); // check on load of the page
```

Comment: Shouldn't you always poll... be it success or error. In this example if for any reason the response is an error. The next poll will not be made.

Comment: It depends on your server really. Generally if you get an error response I wouldn't poll again as you could end up flooding the server with requests which will just compound the problem if it's already not responding. You could add some tolerance to stop requests after a pre-set number of errors, but I'll leave that down to the OP to implement as it's just a case of adding a counter and a `fail` handler - assuming it's even needed in this case.

Comment: Ummm...  I understand what you are trying to say. But at-least a second call could be made, say if there was timeout the first time.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(ajaxcall, 1000); //calls ajaxcall every 1000 microseconds
});

function ajaxcall(){
 $.ajax({
        url: '/tasks/3dbf226a-a7f5-4e9b-8094-4ad1383aa6fd/status/',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json.task.status == 'SUCCESS') {
                // show a message to the user
            } 
        }
    });
}